# How do I get pressed keys correctly?

Tags: javascript, function, object

> function will change snake position by deleting the tail and adding a
> new head in needed direction(VectorX/Y). But when I press any button vectors are don`t changing.

```js
    const canvas = document.getElementById('map');
const cs = canvas.getContext('2d');

function drawSqr(color, size, position){
    cs.fillStyle = color;
    cs.fillRect(position[0] * size, position[1] * size, size, size);
}



const sqrSize = 20;
cs.fillStyle = "#000000";
cs.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

let vectorX = 0, vectorY = 0;

let snake = {
    position : [
        [1, 1],
        [2, 1],
        [3, 1],
    ],
    color: "#00FFFF",
    snakeRender: function(event){
            document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event, vectorX, vectorY){
                switch(event){
                    case "w":
                        vectorX = 0, vectorY = 1;
                        break;
                    case "a":
                        vectorX = -1, vectorY = 0;
                        break;
                    case "s":
                        vectorX = 0, vectorY = -1;
                        break;
                    case "d":
                        vectorX = 1, vectorY = 0;
                        break;
                }
            return alert(event + " was pressed!");
        });
    
        let [x, y] = this.position.at(-1);
        this.position.push([x + vectorX, y + vectorY]);
        let oldTail = this.position.shift()
        console.log(this.position)
        console.log(vectorX, vectorY)
        drawSqr("#000000", sqrSize, oldTail);
        for(let pos of this.position){
            drawSqr(this.color, sqrSize, pos);
        }
        setTimeout(() => snake.snakeRender(), 1000);
    }
};


snake.snakeRender();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <title>The snake</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>
    <canvas id="map" width="1280" height="720"></canvas>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
 </body> 
</html>
```

> P.s vectors will change when you press "W", "A", "S", "D". I think
> problem is in setTimeOut but i don`t know how can i fix this. Thanks
> for your help. P.p.s I have checked does program see the pressed
> buttons and it is returned [object KeyboardEvent]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues:

1. `function(ev, vectorX, vectorY)` means that updating `vectorX` and `vectorY` will update those local variables and not the global ones declared here: `let vectorX = 0, vectorY = 0;`. (And only the global ones are accessible to the updaters.)
2. Using `switch(ev)` instead of `switch(ev.key)` means that it will never match any key, because `ev` is an object, not a string.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('map');
const cs = canvas.getContext('2d');

function drawSqr(color, size, position){
    cs.fillStyle = color;
    cs.fillRect(position[0] * size, position[1] * size, size, size);
}



const sqrSize = 20;
cs.fillStyle = "#000000";
cs.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

let vectorX = 0, vectorY = 0;

let snake = {
    position : [
        [1, 1],
        [2, 1],
        [3, 1],
    ],
    color: "#00FFFF",
    snakeRender: function(event){
            document.addEventListener('keydown', function(ev){
                switch(ev.key){
                    case "w":
                        vectorX = 0, vectorY = 1;
                        break;
                    case "a":
                        vectorX = -1, vectorY = 0;
                        break;
                    case "s":
                        vectorX = 0, vectorY = -1;
                        break;
                    case "d":
                        vectorX = 1, vectorY = 0;
                        break;
                }
            return
        });
    
        let [x, y] = this.position.at(-1);
        this.position.push([x + vectorX, y + vectorY]);
        let oldTail = this.position.shift()
        console.log(this.position)
        console.log(vectorX, vectorY)
        drawSqr("#000000", sqrSize, oldTail);
        for(let pos of this.position){
            drawSqr(this.color, sqrSize, pos);
        }
        setTimeout(() => snake.snakeRender(), 1000);
    }
};


snake.snakeRender();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <title>The snake</title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>
 <body>
    <canvas id="map" width="1280" height="720"></canvas>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
 </body> 
</html>
```

Also, adding an event listener every single time `snakeRender()` runs, means there are many event listeners, each doing the same thing. I didn't adjust anything there, though.

Comment: Yes, it will because `vectorX` and `vectorY` are globals and therefore can be accessed from the event listener anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
switch(ev.key){
    case "w":
        vectorX = 0, vectorY = 1;
    break;
    case "a":
        vectorX = -1, vectorY = 0;
    break;
    case "s":
        vectorX = 0, vectorY = -1;
    break;
    case "d":
        vectorX = 1, vectorY = 0;
    break;
}
```